# Where should I ask non-programming related questions about telecommunication systems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm in the process of brushing up on a series of telecommunication systems and protocols (802.11*, GSM, wireless communication basics, ...) and I wonder which site would be suited best. It doesn't seem to fit on SO, as it doesn't really have to do with implementations. It could border on electrical engineering, but I'm not sure there. The same holds for the computer science beta.

What would be a good site for these things?

Would questions about the robustness against tampering (say, in the case of WiFi or GSM) belong on IT Security?

---

Some samples

> How does using several 8 bit Barker-like codes work in 802.11b to sneak in extra bits?
>
> Why does the combination of OFDM and DSSS in 802.11g allow higher data rates?
>
> What are (are there?) measures that can be taken by GSM [UMTS] providers to prevent competitors from jamming entire cells?

Comment: Drop in a sample question

Comment: @random: I added some sample questions I had in mind right now. I omitted to add more details (which would normally go in the question body). Note that I don't want them answered/discussed here, because I might have more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look over on [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

I think some of the encoding questions may be on topic there, but it never hurts to check on [their Meta](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com) first.

Comment: Actually, I had a look there (for some reason I forgot to mention them when composing *this* question, though) but thought that they wouldn't work for questions above the physical layer, so I mentally discarded them. I guess, I could distribute questions all over the network, though (but it didn't occur to me).

Comment: @bitmask I'm not enough of a specialist to quite grasp why it won't work for questions above the physical layer, but I take your word for it.  All of the encoding should be on topic there, though.

Comment: Well, how you route user data efficiently within your distribution system doesn't really have anything to do with how you decode your user data. But I'll remember that site for questions that deal with low-level stuff.

Comment: @bitmask Ah, yes, I see how that wouldn't necessarily be on topic.  I'm not sure where it would be, though, tbh.  I wouldn't hazard a guess.